# Adding clause to case statement causes query to drag

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a case statement (part of a much longer query):

```
case 
---when datediff('day',l.start_date,current_date) = 0 then 'Listed Today'
        when days_from_start_to_first_inquiry is null then 'No Inquiries Received' 
        when days_from_start_to_first_inquiry <= 0.3989 then 'Yes' 
        else 'No' end as met_time_to_first_inquiry_goal_yn,
```

When the first when is commented out, the query runs in about 28 seconds. When I add it in, the query just stalls and times out. I've tried various approaches - adding the date clause in each line, changing it to `when l.start_date = current_date` etc and I can't get it to run.

Running Redshift on PopSQL.

Any thoughts?
Thanks.

Comment: Please add to your question the Explain Plan output for the 2 versions of the query

Comment: It is hard to imagine that addition this condition to a `case` expression could have any noticeable impact on query performance.

Comment: If there is a complex join tree in play and this is the only reference to l.start_date then this could make a meaningful change to the query plan.  I too would like to see the explain plans.

Answer (score 0):

Is the order of your when important ?

Because the datediff will be executed for each line but if you put it just before the else, no.

You can also try to work with indexes.

Comment: Yes, it is important - the datediff should be first, which is why I just listed it first.